# Pulling data from FINVIZ, unknown reason for an error

Tags: google-sheets

So I used to pull data for Annual Dividend per share from finviz into my google sheet for respective stocks and ETFs but noticed today that the cell has an error **#REF** and the error says **Function INDEX parameter 3 value is 2. Valid values are between 0 and 1**

The formula I am using is:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&REGEXEXTRACT(E9, "[^:]+$") ,"table", 9),7,2),"*","")="-","",SUBSTITUTE(index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&REGEXEXTRACT(E9, "[^:]+$") ,"table", 9),7,2),"*",""))
```

where E9 is the cell containing stock exchange and the symbol in format of **NYSEARCA:VTI**

[Sample google sheet with implementation:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LpM0OHAvCobgfZJpXagR-9EL96oA_0H6WpUlKftweVQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Any reasons why I might be getting this error?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LpM0OHAvCobgfZJpXagR-9EL96oA_0H6WpUlKftweVQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to this problem!
Finviz updated its website and has numbered the table to 8! THus had to change that in the function I have!
So i changed table 9,7,2 to 8,7,2 and it worked